# Is it possible to call an iOS UIAlertView from javascript?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, uialertview

Same old story... designers would like a dialog box that is slightly different from the standard javascript confirm. In this case, the audience is iOS only, so I am wondering if I can use javascript to call the native UIAlertView box (and customize it accordingly). If so, how?

Comment: Is this for an iPhone app or for your mobile website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom URL scheme in your html page, like alertview://somemessage.  Open that URL in the web view using an href or javascript like you'd open any other link.

Now in your UIWebView delegate, add the following method:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if ([[[request URL] scheme] isEqualToString:@"alertview"]) {
         // display UIAlertView here
    }
    return YES;
}
```

You can access the message (if you need to) by looking at the NSURL's path property.

Comment: Thanks. It turns out we do something like this already, elsewhere.